# gmail contact mail id to report error

Tags: gmail, account-management

I need to mail the gmail support team for one Outlook configuration error in my machine for my gmail account.

"Outlook cannot connect to server (POP3 or IMAP) "

Could you please pin point me on the specific gmail contact details?

__Kanu

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can email them directly but have you looked at this article to help you setup GMail in Outlook?

[Setting up Gmail in Outlook 2007](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77689)

You could also try posting a question in the [GMail Help Forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail?hl=en).